# `$s` is not a valid video, depsite having png url

Tags: typescript, aframe

I am working on an angular web project with aframe.

I have a data model that contains rectangular buttons with urls for their image (jpg, png, gif).
When I try to load these textures however, I receive the following warnings:

> components:texture:warn `$s` is not a valid video  https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/...-bed3-06ba2a75717c.png

(url shortened, notice how it is a `png`)

The buttons also appear black with no texture.

Here is how I create my buttons:

```
buttons.forEach((b: ButtonV4) => {
    const button: Entity = document.createElement("a-plane");
    const url: string = this.envService.buildURL(b.image);
    button.setAttribute("src",url);
    button.setAttribute("position",new THREE.Vector3(b.x,b.y,b.z));
    button.setAttribute("rotation",new THREE.Vector3(0,0,b.rotation));
    button.setAttribute("width",b.width);
    button.setAttribute("height",b.height);
    button.setAttribute("material", "transparent: true;");
    sceneRoot.appendChild(button);
});
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit:

I've noticed that it plays Video urls just fine. I.e. supplying a mp4 file makes it play a video as a texture.

Comment: Without a link to reproduce it will be hard to help, investigate and suggest concrete solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe is very handy. FWIW. as per [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/material.html#textures) the syntax for an inline url is `material="src: url(url/to/texture.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is my data server.
The content type is set to `application/octet-stream`, which I can't change (Out of my reach).
aframe seems to interpret this as a mp4/video file automatically.

Since my files end with `png`, `jpg`, `mp4` though, i check for the file ending and create a data url with the correct mime type.

```
return this.http.get<File>(url,{responseType: "blob" as "json",headers}).pipe(
        switchMap((blob: File) => {
            return new Observable<Texture>(
                (obs: Observer<Texture>) => {
                    const fr: FileReader = new FileReader();
                    fr.onload = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
                        let dataUrl: string = e.target.result as string;
                        const mime: string = this.getMimeTypeFromURL(url);
                        dataUrl = dataUrl.replace("application/octet-stream",mime);
                        obs.next(new Texture(url,dataUrl));
                    };
                    fr.onloadend = () => obs.complete();
                    fr.onabort = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => obs.error(e.target.error);
                    fr.onerror = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => obs.error(e.target.error);
                    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
                }
            );
        })
    );
```

---

```
private getMimeTypeFromURL(url: string): string {
        if(url.endsWith("jpg")) {
            return "image/jpg";
        }
        if(url.endsWith("jpeg")) {
            return "image/jpg";
        }
        if(url.endsWith("png")) {
            return "image/png";
        }
        if(url.endsWith("gif")) {
            return "image/gif";
        }
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }
```